# Visual Studio 2013: IIS express, ssl disable but ssl is requiered

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I've recently updated my version of Visual Studio from 2010 to 2013.
I have a web project which i can launch with no problem on 2010.

However every time i try to launch the same project on 2013, i get:

```
Error HTTP 403.4 - Forbidden
```

In 2010 version, I use visual studio development server for debug. However on 2013, there is no such option, so I have to utilize IIS Express. Despite of the project is not  configured to use SSL, it throws me the previously exception.

[image: My solution properties]

Do you know if it's necessary to do further configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config file or the ApplicationHost.config of IIS Express search for

```
<access sslFlags="Ssl" />
```

and remove the whole node.

Comment: I have no such entry on web.config file. Also I checked ApplicationHost.config of IIS Express (which I found on the default folder: C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer) and it has not this text either. The access entry was: <access sslFlags="None" />. However, I removed it with the same result

Comment: I don't know why, but after looking for all the files with that name, I found another one on c:\users\.... The file on this location had that line. Changing it solved my problem. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YourProjectName
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());


        }
    }
}
```

*remove  filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); from app_start folder in FilterConfig > RegisterGlobalFilter >*